# Use of hgroup tag and how much well for SEO it is?

Tags: seo, html5

I used `hgroup` tag like as in section. I want to know that it's well for SEO or not and this is a correct use of `hgroup`.

HTML:

```
<section>      
<hgroup>
          <h1>CCTV Camera's online view on your 3G phone</h1>
          <h6><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> Shadman, Lahore</h6>
          <h6><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 29 Aug 12:22 2014</h6>
          <h6>Ad ID: <span>1249586</span></h6>
          <h6> Views: <span>2</span></h6>
        </hgroup>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section h1{
    font-size:24px;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    line-height:25px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;}
section h6{
    font-size:10px;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    font-weight:normal;
    text-transform:capitalize;
    float:left;
    padding:0 0 0 1%;
    color:#999;}
section h6 i{
    color:#85B7F3;}
section h6:nth-child(4),
section h6:nth-child(5){
    color:#000;
    float:right;
        padding:0 1% 0 0%;}
section h6 span{
    font-weight:bold;}
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`<hgroup>` is not an official HTML tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hgroup) so its use is discouraged and its meaning may change.

Since it is not an official HTML tag it almost certainly has no SEO value. And, even if it did, it would be so small that it wouldn't be worth focusing on.

Answer (score 1):

The `hgroup` element was [removed](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html) from HTML5 more than a year ago.

For alternatives, there is now an own section in HTML5:
[**Subheadings, subtitles, alternative titles and taglines**](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/common-idioms.html#sub-head)

In short, you should not use heading elements (`h1`-`h6`) for the "subtitles" anymore, as they’d create a wrong document outline.

You could use something like this:

```
<section> 
  <header>     
    <h1>CCTV Camera's online view on your 3G phone</h1>
    <!-- just using 'div' in this example; better use more specific markup, see below -->
    <div>Shadman, Lahore</div>
    <div>29 Aug 12:22 2014</div>
    <div>Ad ID: 1249586</div>
    <div>Views: 2</div>
  </header>
</section>
```

Side notes:

- [Don’t use `i` for (font) icons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22501699/1591669). Use `span` instead.
- You could use the `time` element for the publication date.
- You could use the `dl` element for the metadata like "Views" and "Ad ID" (and even for the date and place if you want to provide names in `dt` for them).

Comment: `<i>` is used by millions of websites across the globe, its included in things like bootstrap and font awesome which is used by a BIG chunk of the internet, saying not to use to purely satisfy W3C is invalid when user experience should trump everything. Ya you can use span but again, using i won't harm you.

Comment: @bybe: **1.** Just because it’s used by many, doesn’t mean that it’s good practice. If used so often, you might only assume that it won’t noticeably *hurt*, but I didn’t claim the contrary. **2.** It is probably used by so many sites just because those libraries recommended it. I don’t use Bootstrap, but as far as I understand, they realized the misuse and [document the usage of `span` instead of `i`](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#glyphicons-how-to-use) in the current version. **3.** Which user experience? The developer’s, having to type `span` instead of `i`? Or … performance?

Comment: @unor it's mean i have to use span it's best for the seo in the place i