# Using the <strong/> tag as a call to action

Tags: html, markup, hyperlink

I'm creating a subscription page and there are four packages available for purchase. At the bottom of the package description there's a button link to *Learn More* about the package. In general, is it valid to use the `<strong/>` as a call to action? I've seen it used in the context of of a sentence or within a paragraph but never as its own entity.

**Example**

```
... 
<section>
  <h1>Page Heading</h1>
  <p></p>
</section>

<section>
  <h2>Package Options</h2>

  <div>
    <div>
      <header>                      
        <h3>Package 1></h3>
        <h4>Package 1: Description</h4>
      </header>
      ...
      <a href=""><strong>Learn More</strong></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</section
...
```

Comment: Should be okay. What is your concern? Generally, I would recommend using a div tag and CSS to set this instead of using HTML, however, there is nothing wrong with strong. **One warning:** With HTML 4.*n* and HTML 5, there is a difference in how this tag is used. Here is a link: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_strong.asp

Comment: Personally I'd just use `section a {font-weight: bold;}` as strong is to indicate importance, a link is about relevancy.

Comment: @SimonHayter Thanks for chiming in with your expertise. I forgot more on many IT subjects than I ever knew. (please do not do the math on this one... you might agree.)

Comment: @closetnoc, @SimonHayter In this context I'm using `<strong/>` to indicate that **Learn More** is an important action. More concerned about semantics than styling.

Comment: Ah ha! You are in my territory now. *Learn More* has no semantic weight at all. However, *Learn more about widget manufacturing.* does. As well, using strong, bold, italics does not influence this at all. However, link text is a major semantic factor so just a link would be good enough. Just make sure that the link gives as many clues to what it links to as possible without getting silly as poop. Where it makes sense, it is far better to link to resources within related content. In this case, the content supports the link and target semantically.

Comment: @closetnoc Thanks. So with that being said, should `<strong/>` be used in manner of writing paragraphs and sentences as mentioned in the original question?

Comment: I use bold. I assume that is what you are going for. In HTML 4.*n*, strong is the same as bold, but in HTML 5, it can be interpreted differently. I never use strong really. But it should be okay.

Comment: Well I'm not sure if I'd consider them the same. Per W3C: *The <strong> tag is a phrase tag. It defines important text.* while *The <b> tag specifies bold text.* The overall aim is to indicate (browser wise) that this, being the *Learn More* link is important amongst other links or text.

Comment: Side note about your example markup: Unless you omitted additional headings in that `section`, it seems that you are using the `h3` as some kind of subheading. If that’s the case, you [shouldn’t use a heading element](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/68608/17633) for this.

Comment: @unor Thanks for pointing that out. I fixed my code to best represent what I'm currently working on. Does it look okay now?

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5, the [`strong` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-strong-element) can be used for "strong importance, seriousness, or urgency".

I think none of these three cases matches your example, so you should not use the `strong` element. While "importance" may sound relevant, the definition makes clear that it’s for *distinguishing* the important part from other parts, but that doesn’t seem to be the case in your example.

Comment: yep... exactly :)